# Setting the print area to a Range greater than 255 characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I've written some VBA code to define a somewhat complicated Range that I'd like to set the print area of a worksheet to be. However, when I set the print area via

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = myRange.Address
```

the print area is seemingly truncated to the first 255 characters of my range.

What are my options to print (well actually save to a .pdf) only my defined range? I'd like to avoid anything too manual since I'm working with ~150 workbooks. I'm using Excel 2016 64 bit.

I'm aware of a similar question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410374/increase-the-maximum-string-length-of-excel-printarea) but the accepted solution is rather unsatisfactory, since the page numbering in the generated pdfs would not be correct.

Comment: "the print area is seemingly truncated to the first 255 characters of my range." That is an inbuilt limitation of Excel printing code.

Comment: So the answer is that no, what I want to do is not possible?

Comment: As far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

These are more work-arounds than fixes.  Use macros where possible like #1

1. Hide all of the cells you don't want to print.  Print A1:z99.  Unhide all the cells.
2. Create a new sheet temporary or not.

test

```
sub macro1()
Location = "A1 B2:B10 C4:C10 "
Position = 1

While (Position < Len(Location))

found = InStr(Position, Location, " ")

if found=0 then found=len(location)

    printRange = Mid(Location, Position, (found - Position))
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range(printRange).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range(printRange).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Position = found + 1

Wend
End Sub
```

print the whole temporary sheet.

Delete(or not) temporary sheet.

3. Similiar to #2 but you can also you

   temp.a1= concatenate(a1,a2,a5,a7,a8,a11)